# Add jqGrid data back to json

Tags: jqgrid

Using inline edit for jqGrid :

I have json data in a variable 'jsonDataStr'. The data is displayed using jqGrid.

```
 $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
            colModel: [
                { name: 'authenticate', width: "80" ,align: 'center',formatter: 'checkbox',editable:true,edittype:"checkbox", editoptions:{value: "Yes:No"}, formoptions:{ rowpos:1, label: "Authenticate ", elmprefix:"(*)"},editrules:{required:true} },
                { name: 'authorize', width: "80" ,align: 'center',formatter: 'checkbox',editable:true,edittype:"checkbox", editoptions:{value: "Yes:No"}, formoptions:{ rowpos:1, label: "Authorize ", elmprefix:"(*)"},editrules:{required:true}},
            ],
            pager: '#pagerTable',
            colNames:[ 'authenticate','authorize'],
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: jsonDataStr,
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
            viewrecords: true,pginput : false, forceFit :true,
            height: 83,caption :"Permissions",
            ignoreCase: true,scrollBar : false
        });


        $("#myGrid").navGrid("#pagerTable",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});
        $("#myGrid").inlineNav("#pagerTable");
```

It is getting displayed properly.

Now when I save row, I want to save data to the same json variable,'jsonDataStr'. Moreover, I want to add information to the json row,

such as added, modified or deleted. Is there any easy way to do this?

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpfull

```
var jsonDataStr = "some Data you need";
$("#YourGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { jsonDataStr: jsonDataStr }); 
$('#YourGrid').trigger('reloadGrid');
```